# Get url of clicked hyperlink inside a Windows Forms Application WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, hyperlink, browser

If someone clicks on a hyper link inside a WebBrowser control , what method can i use to get the url of that hyperlink and check if it has an attribute that tells the browser to open the link in a new tab/window. Windows Forms Application.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the element that currently has user input focus using the `Document.ActiveElement` property.

```
private void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        HtmlElement currentElement = webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement;
        if (currentElement != null)
        {
            string targetPath = currentElement.GetAttribute("href");

            //You can perform some logic here to determine if the targetPath conformsto your specification and if so...
            MainForm newWindow = new MainForm();
            newWindow.webBrowser1.Navigate(targetPath);
            newWindow.Show(); 

           //Otherwise
           //webBrowser1.Navigate(targetPath);

        }
    }
}
```